# when i upload file in filezilla then filezilla deleted file functions.php. I give coding below

Tags: php

```
if($_SESSION['isstaff'] == 1){
 $qry1 = "select * from ".DB_PREFIX."username where username ='".$_SESSION['username']."' and password='".$_SESSION['password']."' and status=1";
}else{
 $qry1 = "select * from ".DB_PREFIX."pdetail where rollno =".$_SESSION['username']." and password='".$_SESSION['password']."' and remark=1";
}
```

When I apply single qry then Filezilla accept this file but in if else condition it will not accept function.php file

Comment: what actually u need?

Comment: its working fine with `if($_SESSION['isstaff'] == 1){
 $qry1 = "select * from ".DB_PREFIX."username where username ='".$_SESSION['username']."' and password='".$_SESSION['password']."' and status=1";
}`

Comment: it working fine but when upload file in filezilla then filezilla deleted function.php file in which this coding. The problem is that filezilla detect malware in this coding.